# How can I access the value of the upper left data in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have this pandas dataframe:

```
   Gender My Personal Value
0    Male               YES
1  Female                NO
2  Female               YES
3    Male                NO
4  Female               YES
5  Female                NO
6  Female               YES
7    Male                NO
```

Then I use crosstab function this way:

```
>>> b = pd.crosstab(a['Gender'],a['My Personal Value'])
```

And get this second dataframe:

```
>>> b
My Personal Value  NO  YES
Gender                    
Female              2    3
Male                2    1
```

In my first dataframe, column names are:

```
>>> a.columns.values
array(['Gender', 'My Personal Value'], dtype=object)
```

In my second dataframe, column names are:

```
>>> b.columns.values
array(['NO', 'YES'], dtype=object)
```

What is "My Personal Value" to this second dataframe, and how cant I access that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `columns.name`:

```
print (b.columns.name)
My Personal Value
```

---

```
print (b.index.name)
Gender
```

Comment: Thanks. I found a way using axes, but of course your answer is the right solution.